# string to date with javascript function

Tags: javascript

Am i on the right track to parse a string to date in javascript? i need an output of 2021-09-29 im looking for a better solution.

```js
months = ["January", "February", "March", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novemeber", "Decemeber"]

function parseDateString(date) {
  var month = date.months();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  return month, day, year;
}
console.log(parseDateString('September 1, 2021'))
```

Comment: Will your input to parseDateString always be 'Month day, year'?

Comment: Please tell us the format that your input is expected to follow and the wanted result.

Comment: expected format is expected to be YYYY-MM-DD always and i need to put a throw error in there as well is the object isnt in expected format